# SQL subquery filter using parent table fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query as below:

```
 SELECT tr.AccountFK ,
          TransactionRequestStatus = CASE
            WHEN tr.TransactionRequestStatusFK  = 2 THEN 'Accepted' 
            ELSE 'Rejected'
        END,
        tr.TransactionRequestID

         FROM [CRM].[acc].[TransactionRequest] as tr
         INNER JOIN CRM.acc.TransactionRequestHistory as trh
         ON tr.TransactionRequestID = trh.TransactionRequestFK
         where tr.TransactionRequestTypeFK = 3 --bill split
         and TransactionRequestStatusFK in (2, 3) --Approved, Rejected  

         --Filter- on each item
         and (tr.TransactionRequestStatusFK = 2 and tr.TransactionRequestID not in (select tr.TransactionRequestID from crm.acc.TransactionRequest tr
                                    INNER JOIN CRM.acc.TransactionRequestHistory as trh
                                    ON tr.TransactionRequestID = trh.TransactionRequestFK
                                    where tr.TransactionRequestID = trh.TransactionRequestFK
                                    and trh.EventFK = 15)
                or
                tr.TransactionRequestStatusFK = 3 and  tr.Notes not like '%No Action%')  
        group by tr.AccountFK, tr.TransactionRequestStatusFK, tr.TransactionRequestID
```

I have a subquery in the where clause to apply a filter on each item but this subquery join is the same has the join in the main query, is there any way to re-use the main query table and avoid repeating same code in the subquery.

Comment: use temporary tables instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CTE`. Assuming the column names in both `crm.acc.TransactionRequest` and `CRM.acc.TransactionRequestHistory` are distinct, the following should work. If they aren't, then you'll have to specify the columns with their alias in the `Select` of cte.

```
with cte as
(select * from crm.acc.TransactionRequest tr
                                    INNER JOIN CRM.acc.TransactionRequestHistory as trh
                                    ON tr.TransactionRequestID = trh.TransactionRequestFK)

SELECT AccountFK ,
          TransactionRequestStatus = CASE
            WHEN TransactionRequestStatusFK  = 2 THEN 'Accepted' 
            ELSE 'Rejected'
        END,
        TransactionRequestID

         FROM cte
         where TransactionRequestTypeFK = 3 --bill split
         and TransactionRequestStatusFK in (2, 3) --Approved, Rejected  

         --Filter- on each item
         and (TransactionRequestStatusFK = 2 and TransactionRequestID not in 
         (select TransactionRequestID from cte
                                      where TransactionRequestID = TransactionRequestFK
                                      and EventFK = 15)
                or
                TransactionRequestStatusFK = 3 and  Notes not like '%No Action%')  
        group by AccountFK, TransactionRequestStatusFK, TransactionRequestID
```